# Scheme function applying a function to all elements in a list, no matter how deep, while preserving the structure of the list

Tags: scheme, racket

Hey, I'm working on a homework question about applying a function to every element in a list, going as deep as needed.

I am getting a error when calling (fun (car l)), that

```
mcar: expects argument of type <mutable-pair>; given 5
```

and yet when I just call (fun l) i get the error
+: expects type  as 1st argument, given: (5); other arguments were: 1

```
   (define (map-gen fun l)
    (if (null? fun) l 
        (if (null? l) '()
            (if (list? (car l))
                (append (map-gen fun (cdr l)) (map-gen fun (car l)))
                (append (map-gen fun (cdr l)) (fun (car l)))))))
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

edit: This is when calling the function like so:

```
(map-gen (lambda (x) (+ x 1))'(1 (2 (3 4))(((5)))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the arguments for appends backwards, and I think cons would be a better bet.  Also, checking to see if fun is null is unnecessary.

```
(define (map-gen fun l)
   (if (null? l) '()
       (if (list? (car l))
           (cons (map-gen fun (car l)) (map-gen fun (cdr l)))
           (cons (fun (car l)) (map-gen fun (cdr l))))))
```

Also, as Eli says in his answer, you really should look into cond instead of nested ifs.  It's much more elegant, making your code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems:

- the `fun` input is expected to be a function, so asking `(null? fun)` doesn't make much sense,
- your use of nested `if`s is exactly the kind of thing that `cond` solves much more elegantly,
- as Keen said, when you deal with deconstructing lists this way, `cons` is much more appropriate,
- asking `(list? (car l))` is broken -- at that point you know that `l` is not the empty list, but what if it's not a list at all?

A good way to approach this is to think about the kind of `l` inputs you need to deal with:

- it can be the empty list, and in that case the answer is simple,
- it can be a pair (best to test that with `pair?`, although `list?` will work too if you're not worried about "improper lists"), in this case you need to do something with its `car` and with its `cdr` and combine the results in a way that matches the original structure (this is easy),
- or it can be something else (and this case is easy too).

It's best to start with writing several examples of how you'd want it to run, then fill out the code to implement it, and finally turn the examples into test cases to verify that your solution works.  You should really see [HtDP](http://htdp.org/) for this -- the "design recipe" that it talks about makes solving such problems so easy that the solution will practically write itself.  (Given that you're doing this in some course, it might be a good idea to point this out to your teacher.)